# Choose the 32 or 64 bit version of an app from command line

Tags: macos, architecture, command-line, x86-64, i386

I'm on Mac OS X, and I have an executable binary which is compatible with the x86_64 and i386 architectures.

From the command-line, I would like to **choose which of these architectures has to be launched**.

How to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$ executable_file
```

enter either:

```
$ arch -i386 executable_file
```

or:

```
$ arch -x86_64 executable_file
```